# navigation child links behind div css z-index

Tags: css, navigation, position, z-index

I can get my z-index to work on the left (vertical) navigation on the following page, when hovering over the 'Refurbishments' parent link - the child links go behind the main content to the right:

http://www.mbc.theinternetconsultancy.co.uk

Any idea's?

Comment: may i know in which browser you are facing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Following steps.

> 1. open menu-styles.css go to line no 20    Remove position:relative.
> 2. open custom.css go to line no 543 (top not required)    remove this -> div.sidebar-left ul.joostrapmenu li ul.collapse { top: -1px; }
> 3. in same custom.css go to line no 529 remove top:0 (please put as it is left: 160px)
> 4. now open menu-styles.css go to line no 84    remove top: 40px from there.

After these steps, "caret" of right side not work fine right ?
go to menu-styles.css and line no 36 and change top to 52% or you can adjust by your own.

Hope now it will work fine!

Comment: no... that doesn't work on the left menu. did you get it to work in chrome inspector or firebug?